# Intellij IDEA shows errors in jpa native queries

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I have bunch of native queries in my project, all of them having Spring Data @Query annotation methods, and IDEA shows errors in all of them, probably thinking it's jpa queries.
E.g.
[image: TRUNCATE error]  [image: SELECT * error]

`@SuppressWarnings("JpaQlInspection")` Doesn't work, i suppose because it's not warning
Only workaround i've found to exclude errors from analysis is to completely disable jpql syntax check, and i'd prefer to have it. 
Is there any way?

Comment: I see the same issue.  Looks like a bug.  I added  @SuppressWarnings("all")  to a method that was triggering this inspection to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. This has apparently been fixed for 2017.1.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126972

Comment: Looks like it's not fixed in EAP, but i think it's an answer to my question

Comment: Its not fixed as of July 2020 , though its marked as fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Its not fixed till 2021.1.3 version of Intellij idea.
But you can disable this Code Analyzer feature by going to Setting->Editor->Inspections, and search for **SQL Unresolved reference** and disable it.